# WCF service Post error on IIS 6

Tags: json, wcf, iis-7.5, http-status-code-405

I have developed a REST service that used to run localy on my PC and had no issues!!I have hosted my wcf on a windows server 2008-r2 IIS 7.5, in order to call my service from an IP. I am using the get method with a JSON and all works fine, but  when i try the post( with chrome plugin) i get 405 error  and 500 error. I checked the MIME-TYPES and added json for IIS. Any solution or suggestiong how to resolve this error would be very useful.
I will post my webconfig and ISERVICE files as well.

My webConfig file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="RestService.RestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="RestService.IRestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="Services.webHttpBehavior">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
          <behavior name="Services.webHttpBehavior">
              <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" />
          </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
      <diagnostics>
          <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
      </diagnostics>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
      <!--  <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json"/>
        </staticContent>-->
  </system.webServer>
    <system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\wcflog3.txt" />
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
    </system.diagnostics>

</configuration>
```

My Service Implementtion is as followes:

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "xml/{str}")]
        string XMLData(string str);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            UriTemplate = "jsoncheckifexists")]
        bool CheckIfExists(RestService.RestServiceImpl.UrlObject data);
```

The GET is working just fine, I try the POST calling the function CheckIfExists:

```
public bool CheckIfExists(UrlObject urlObject)
{
  string link= urlObject.url;
//Standard logon to CRM procedure(Framework)
if abc=true
     return true;
else false;
}
```

Comment: Windows Server 2008 R2 and IIS **6**?  Are you sure about that?

Comment: You are so right!!IIS 7.5.7600.16385 to be totally accurate, so 7.5. Thanks for help!